# How display alert before MauiApp created?

Tags: c#, android, maui

In my project maui on android i create services, load some data and then add to MauiApp:

```
var myService=new();   
myService.LoadData();//here can throw exception
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(myService);
```

Some services during loading can throw exception. Now exception shutdown app without any information.
DisplayAlert work only with Page, but Page will creating in App later.
In Xamarin i used Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder with Android.App.Application.Context and everything working.In Maui with Android.App.Application.Context working only Toast message else thow exception:

> `Android.Views.WindowManagerBadTokenException: 'Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?'`

Platform.CurrentActivity is null before App not started. Can i get Context of SplashScreen to display exception or how can i display text of exception message before app started?

Comment: seems like logging can be better for what you are trying to achieve, showing technical errors as alerts is not a good practice

Comment: It is not logging. It is show exception message text why the app can not be started and after this shutdown. Now if i have some mistake in code my app not started without any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't because the app didn't start as you said.

Splash screen is just a photo you can't write text here. For more detail check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/splashscreen?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android)

If you don't want to call your services at all after application started, you can set a variable for this in `MauiProgram.cs`;

```
internal static string errorMessage = string.Empty; // You can modify this as a class or bool.

try
{
    var myService = new();
    myService.LoadData();//here can throw exception

    // Service 2

    // Service 3 <- if it throws an exception here, the following services will not be started.

    // Service 4

    // Service 5
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    errorMessage = ex.Message;
}

var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(myService);
```

and where you open the main screen, you can have the error you want displayed, if any. So you should change your `App.xaml.cs` file like this;

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(MauiProgram.errorMessage))
        {
            MainPage = new MainPage();
        }
        else
        {
            MainPage = new ContentPage() { Content = new StackLayout() };
        }
    }

    protected async override void OnStart()
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(MauiProgram.errorMessage))
        {
           return; 
        }

        await MainPage.DisplayAlert("Exception during ap load!", _exception.Message, "OK");
        Quit();
    }

}
```

when you run this code, it calls your services first. Then builds the app and opens error message if there is any errors.

Comment: thank you for your answer. 1. and 2.  not working because creating of service also can throw exception and app use loaded data. 3. Working but  but not so good. Can i start some temp app without mauiapp build  with page where i will show exceptions and after create all services run mauiapp build and my app main?

Comment: It is not a good practice to create and run a new project or app for this function. I've updated my answer according to the new information and your feedback. If this solution doesn't work either, I'll have to ask you to provide your entire `MauiProgram.cs` file.

Comment: thank you for your idea, i use it to create my version.  I can not use your version because i have many services starts one by one and they have dependences from each other if one throw exception i can not create next service i must stop. That why I can not run same app and i run another AppException. You can see my answer. Do you know how can i start my AppException without MauiApp? Which command start app in Maui?

Comment: You don't need another `AppExcepion` class for this. If you put all the services in a single try-catch block, if any of your services fails when you run the program, the error screen will appear without starting your other services. The rest of the code is not executed when the exception is thrown. I've updated my answer according to your explanation.

Answer (score -1):

My modify @Erdogans version:

> ```
>  public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()     
>  {
>     try
>     {
>         var myService = new();
>         myService.LoadData();//here can throw exception
>         return CreateAppNormal();
>     }
>     catch (Exception exception)
>     {
>         return CreateAppException(exception);
>     }
> }
>
> private static MauiApp CreateAppException(Exception exception)
> {     
>    return MauiApp.CreateBuilder().UseMauiApp(p=>new >AppException(exception)).Build();
> }
>
> private static MauiApp CreateAppNormal()
> {
>     var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
>     builder
>         .UseMauiApp<App>()
>         .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
>         {
>             fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
>             fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
>         });
>
>     builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
>     builder.Services.AddSingleton(MyServices);
>
>
>     return builder.Build();
> }
> ```

Code AppException:

> ```
> public class AppException : Application
> {
>     private readonly Exception _exception;
>
>     public AppException(Exception exception)
>     {
>         _exception = exception;
>         MainPage = new ContentPage() { Content = new StackLayout() };
>     }
>
>
>     protected async override void OnStart()
>     {
>         await MainPage.DisplayAlert("Exception during ap load!", _exception.Message, "OK");
>         Quit();
>     }
>
> }
> ```